# Rigorously proving Infimum of a set

Tags: real-analysis

How do I rigorously prove and determine the the greatest lower bound (infimum) of the following set?
$$A =\left\{\frac y{2y+3x}: x,y∈ℝ\text{ and }1≤x<y\right\}$$

This is my attempt: (please let me know if it’s right or if there are other ways to prove it)

The search for the greatest lower bound must begin by determining whether the set is bounded below. We check this as follows:

As $x≥1$ and $y>x,$ we have $2y+3x<2y+3y=5y,$ so:

$\frac y{2y+3x}>\frac15$ for every $x,y≥1$ such that $y>x.$

That is, $\frac15$ is a lower bound for $\frac y{2y+3x}$ under the conditions $1≤x<y.$

Of course there are infinitely many lower bounds for the set. To determine the infimum of $A,$ one has to find the largest of them.

One way to prove that it is $\frac15$ is by showing that there is a sequence of points $(x_n,y_n)$ in the region of the plane where $1≤x<y,$ such that the sequence $a_n=\frac{y_n}{2y_n+3x_n}$ converges to $\frac15.$ If it converges, then for every $ε>0$ there will exist a number of the form $\frac y{2y+3x}$ under the conditions $1≤x<y$ which will be smaller than $\frac15+ε,$ which is the property that characterises the greatest lower bound among all lower bounds.

Let $x_n=y_n −\frac1n$ for every $n≥2;$ for $y_n=n$ we have:

$$\frac{y_n}{2y_n+3x_n}=\frac n{5n−3/n}=\frac1{5− 3/n^2}$$

and of these, the numerator is constant equal to $1$ and the denominator converges to $5,$ so the fraction converges to $\frac15.$

(We also notice that $x_n=n$ and $y_n=n+1$ would have worked as well.)

[Original statement of the exercise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9eZQ.jpg)

Comment: And infmum of the empty set if $\infty$ !

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933): show some work. We are glad to help, not to do your homework for you. (And [format your formulas](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).) Hint: $\frac{2y+3x}y=2+3\frac xy.$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please don't pay attention to that bot. Your question is clear now, but is still lacking of "context". You don't show any attempt.

Comment: I’ve edited my question with my attempted answer. Could you check it, please?

Comment: Please use MathJax to format your equations.

Comment: Can someone tell me if my answer is right and complete?

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is perfect. A more generic argument for the second part is:
$\frac{y_n}{2y_n+3x_n}=\frac1{2+3\frac{x_n}{y_n}}\to\frac15$ as soon as $t_n:=\frac{x_n}{y_n}\to1,$ and there are many sequences of pairs $(x_n,t_n)$ such that $x_n\ge1,0<t_n<1,$ and $t_n\to1.$

A shorter proof, as [hinted in my first comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4812561/timeline#comment_10238946), is to first identify the set $B$ of reciprocals of the elements of $A:$
$$\begin{align}B&=\left\{\frac{2y+3x}y: x,y∈ℝ\text{ and }1≤x<y\right\}\\
&=\left\{2+3\frac xy: x,y∈ℝ\text{ and }1≤x<y\right\}\\
&=\left\{2+3t:0<t<1\right\}\\
&=(2,5),
\end{align}$$
hence
$$A=\left(\frac15,\frac12\right),\text{ so }\inf A=\frac15.$$

Comment: Than you very much for your generous help!

Comment: Congratulations for your fruitful efforts! Please [don't thank in comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).